# Global extrema at the boundary of a function with 2 variables

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, maxima-minima

I have this function $(x, y) \rightarrow e^{(x-1)²+(y-1)²} $ for $f: K \rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ with $K=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R²} | x²+y²\leq4,x\geq0\text{\}} $.

I know that $(1,1)$ is a global minimum and I suspect that $(0, \pm2)$ are the other extreme points, but how do I show that mathematically precise?

Answer (score 1):

Calling

$$
\cases{
p = (x,y)\\
p_0=(1,1)\\
f(p) = e^{\|p-p_0\|^2}
}
$$

we can define the Lagrangian

$$
\mathcal{L}(p,\lambda, s) = f(p) + \lambda(\|p\|^2-4+s^2) 
$$

with $\lambda$ a lagrange multiplier and $s$ a slack variable to transform the restriction inequality into an equation. Now the stationary points are the solutions for

$$
\nabla \mathcal{L}=\cases{
2(p-p_0)e^{\|p-p_0\|^2}+2\lambda p = 0\\
\|p\|^2-4+s^2 = 0\\
\lambda s = 0
}
$$

or equivalently

$$
\nabla \mathcal{L}=\cases{
(p-p_0)+\Lambda p = 0\\
\|p\|^2-4+s^2 = 0\\
\Lambda s = 0
}
$$

with $\Lambda = \lambda e^{-\|p-p_0\|^2}$. Solving for $\{p,\Lambda,s\}$ we have

$$
\left[
\begin{array}{ccccc}
f & x & y & \Lambda & s^2\\
 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 2 \\
 e^{2 \left(\sqrt{2}-1\right)^2} & \sqrt{2} & \sqrt{2} & \frac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt{2}-2\right) & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$

Here $s=0$ means that the restriction is actuating